# Как правильно указать classpath для jar файлов в Intellij IDEA 2020.2?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

Скачал jar файл javax.mail. И никак не могу понять как его засунуть в classpath. Из-за этого программа кидает NoClassDefFoundError. Как решить?

Answer (score 1):

В IntelliJ вы конфигурируете используемые библиотеки, а при запуске все библиотеки добавляются в `classpath` самой IDE.

Что добавить библиотеку в проект в структуре проекта выбираете `Project Settings` -> `Libraries` -> `+` -> `Java`:

[image: добавление библиотеки в проект Intellij]